# Change font size in data-content

Tags: css, html

I have created code like this :

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title data-content="
<ul>
 <li>Booking Period is from Immediately</li>
 <li>Travelling Period</li>
</ul>" data-original-title>
```

I got that `<ul>` from this code :

```
<a class="text-info" href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" 
                                                    title="" 
                                                    data-content="<?=$row_rates['data']->description?>">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:22px"></i>
                                                </a>
```

How can I change the font size of content in `<li>` tag ?

Comment: `<li style="font-size:28px;"></li>` or using external css `li { font-size:28px; }`. Your html isn't valid, you cannot have an unordered list inside an anchor tag's data-content

Comment: You can use internal style to change that.

Comment: I just edited my question. Can you look again ? @PrajwalKM

Comment: I just edited my question. Can you look again ? @LukaKerrΔ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style .popover ul li{font-size:28px;color:red;}

try it below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    delay: 10 // this is definitely needed !
  });
});

// Listen for inserted template to DOM
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
  // Create the inside link.
  $inside = $('<ul class="divider"><li>Booking Period is from Immediately</li><li>Travelling Period</li></ul>');
  // Add the click event-handler only once
  $('.popover-content').append($inside[0])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href='#' class='btn' title ='Test' data-trigger='focus' data-toggle='popover' data-html='true' id = 'testOutside'>Click Here </a>
```

Comment: In that what you want to change. can you upload working example like my answer.

Comment: I this case after I got the value of data-content from the database and the format value is inside <ul> tag.

Comment: @Nicholas add .text-info ul li{font-size:28px;} this to your stylesheet.

Comment: @Nicholas what you want in your code. explain clearly.

Comment: I want to change the font size of content inside popover modal. I got the value of the content is from the database. My html code is the second code in my question and after that code running and get value from database that code become the first code in my question.

Comment: @Nicholas try this .text-info ul li{font-size:28px;}

Comment: @Nicholas     .popover ul li{font-size:28px;color:red;} try this it works.

Comment: Okay thats work. One question again how could I change the background color of the overall popover ?

Comment: @Nicholas .popover {background:red;}

Comment: @Nicholas  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title data-content="
<ul>
<style>
li{
font:size:20px;
}
</style>
 <li>Booking Period is from Immediately</li>
 <li>Travelling Period</li>
</ul>" data-original-title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
ul > li {
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font by inline css as

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title data-content="
<ul style="font-size:20px" /*as font-size you want*/>
 <li>Booking Period is from Immediately</li>
 <li>Travelling Period</li>
</ul>" data-original-title>

or By internal css as

   <style>
    ul li {
        font-size:20px; /*as font-size you want*/
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style in your HTML page

```
a>ul>li{
font-size:15px;
}
```